# How to install a package of another architecture

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, arm, cross-compilation

I want to cross compile from my Intel i7 for a Raspberry Pi4.
Now I added the following to my `sources.list`:

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main restricted
```

which seems to make the packages available for apt.
Now, when I try to install a dev library, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11proto-dri2-dev:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package x11proto-dri2-dev:armhf is a virtual package provided by:
  x11proto-dri2-dev 2018.4-4
  x11proto-dev 2018.4-4
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'x11proto-dri2-dev:armhf' has no installation candidate
```

I am not really sure how to solve this, because IMO `x11proto-dri2-dev 2018.4-4` should have already been the software, I want to install.

Comment: You will probably have no choice but to "configure" your architecture package from source. You already know it is  NOT pre-recompiled in repository as apt-get  format you used . Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this more, I think the error message is at least misleading.

`x11proto-dri2-dev` is in bionic and later a transitional package for arch `all`. It is superseded by `x11proto-dev`.

`x11proto-dev`, is in bionic and later a package containing headers for arch `all`.

So following me issuing a non-fulfilling install command, it seems that apt is only handling arch problems sub-optimally. At least I had wished for error messages pointing me to package only being available in architecture `all`.